# What happens when potassium chloride, potassium dichromate and concentrated sulphuric acid react?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

What happens when $\ce{KCl}$, $\ce{K2Cr2O7}$, and concentrated $\ce{H2SO4}$ reacts?

I have no idea how to approach these questions. I'd love if anybody can help me see the logic behind this.

Answer (score 5):

When a mixture of  $\ce{KCl}$, $\ce{K2Cr2O7}$, conc. $\ce{H2SO4}$ and heated, then they produce [Chromyl chloride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromyl_chloride) ($\ce{CrO2Cl2}$) , $\ce{KHSO4}$, $\ce{H2O}$ are formed.
$$\ce{K2Cr2O7 +4KCl + 6H­_2SO4 → 2CrO2Cl2 +6KHSO4 + 3H2O}$$
The above reaction is commonly known as chromyl chloride test, used for testing the presence of $\ce{Cl-}$ ion in inorganic qualitative analysis.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the properties of the compounds involved.

Dichromate ($\ce{Cr(VI), Cr2O7^{2-}}$) is a strong oxidant and is reduced to $\ce{Cr(III)}$ if it finds a suitable partner (which then is oxidized).

Here, a potential partner in a redox reaction is chloride: $\ce{2 Cl- + 2 e^{-} -> Cl2}$.

Comment: The redox reaction doesn't takes place. This is a famous test to chloride ion, know as the chromyl chloride test. It is an non redox reaction.

Answer (score 1):

I like the question above, since it gives a general strategy.

I'll point out that mixing dichromates and sulfuric acid makes "dichromix" and there are a complicated mixture of (chromic acid)[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromic_acid] and related compounds. Depending on pH and other factors, you can have chromates, dichromates, and even sulfur-chromate mixed ions.

At one point chromic acid was used to clean glassware, since they are very strong oxidizing agents.

**SAFETY NOTE** The use of chromic acid (aka "chromerge") is highly unsafe and [**not** recommended!](http://chemlab.truman.edu/Miscellaneous_files/Cleaning.htm)